# Pass variables around the around method modifier

Tags: perl, moose, method-modifier

Is it possible to pass variables between multiple calls to the `around` [MethodModier](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Moose/lib/Moose/Manual/MethodModifiers.pod#BEFORE,_AFTER,_AND_AROUND)? example (that doesn't work but hopefully conveys what I want to do)

```
sub mysub { ... };

around 'mysub' => sub {
   my $orig = shift;
   my $self = shift;

   my $value = get_value;

   $self->orig(@_);
};

around 'mysub' => sub {
   my $orig = shift;
   my $self = shift;
   my $value = shift;

   my $output
       = "sometext $value"
       . $self->orig(@_);
       . 'someothertext $value'
       ;
};
```

I'd eventually like to have these 'arounds' placed in pluggable traits, where I won't really know which ones are loaded beforehand but the final output will be neatly formatted.

It's possible that I'm thinking about this completely wrong, so other suggestions welcome.

Comment: How about using instance variables?

Comment: @jmz instance variables?

Comment: Like `$self->{value} = get_value;` .... `my $value = $self->{value};`

Comment: @jmz that works... why didn't I think of that... thanks.

Comment: @jmz although I find it odd that the order of the around's is the exact opposite of what I'd think it would be, in order for it to work correctly.

Comment: @xenoterracide: MethodModifier documentation is quite clear that the order is around2..around1...orig.

Comment: @jmz yeah... I read the docs on it... anyways that's not so much a problem, though I realized I need to build on your solution a bit. I think I need to use a LIFO stack.

Comment: @jmz: by "instance variables" I hope you mean attributes.  If I saw `$self->{value} = ...` in a Moose module I would slap the programmer.  @xenoterracide: `around` application on a method *is* a LIFO stack.

Comment: @Ether obviously but I need more than just the `around` for this. read the Catalyst Documentation? it's full of `$self->{value}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an instance variable:

```
$self->{value} = get_value;
...
my $value = $self->{value};
```

<sub>(*See question commments for an actual answer. I'm just reiterating it here, so I can accept an answer, thanks to:*</sub>

[image: jmz])

Comment: as a side note I did not end up using this pattern for implementation, I simply let go of this goal.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do don't have logic.

> "An around modifier receives the
>   original method as its first argument,
>   then the object, and finally any
>   arguments passed to the method."

https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose::Manual::MethodModifiers#BEFORE-AFTER-AND-AROUND