# accessing a Moose Array

Tags: perl, moose

Having trouble figuring out the syntax (which I'm sure is obvious and I'm stupid) for pushing to a Moose array. This is a continuation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486932/pass-variables-around-the-around-method-modifier). it seems to me that I need to more than a simple value for my specific case. Trying to implement it using a Moose-ish way (maybe that's wrong?) but I'm obviously not doing it right.

```
use Moose::Role;
has 'tid_stack' => (
    traits => ['Array'],
    is     => 'rw',
    isa    => 'ArrayRef[Str]',
    default => sub { [] },
);


around 'process' => sub {
    my $orig = shift;
    my $self = shift;
    my ( $template ) = @_;

    $self->tid_stack->push( get_hrtid( $template ) );

    $self->$orig(@_)
};
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've misunderstood what `traits => ['Array']` does.  That allows you to set up `handles` methods.  It does not allow you to call methods like `push` directly.  You need to `use Moose::Autobox` for that (and you don't need the Array trait).

Or you could do:

```
has 'tid_stack' => (
    traits => ['Array'],
    is     => 'rw',
    isa    => 'ArrayRef[Str]',
    default => sub { [] },
    handles => {
      push_tid => 'push',
    },
);

...

    $self->push_tid( get_hrtid( $template ) );
```

Comment: ugh... tried this.... it's driving me nuts... I know that get_hrtid returns the proper thing... but when I try to push it like this it's still not working, moose later complains of trying to operate on empty arrays.

Comment: @xenoterracide: I can't see anything wrong with the above code, can you give a more detailed error description? What code are you currently trying, and what is the error you get?

Comment: with the help of debolaz I have seemingly figured out what was wrong with what I was trying... apparently I needed to make it `lazy` (on top of this) though why that fixed my problem I haven't yet determined.

Comment: @xenoterracide, maybe your `around` method was getting called during object initialization and `tid_stack` wasn't initialized yet?  Making it lazy causes it to get initialized on demand.